# Comparing dates in android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite, date-comparison

I'm comparing two dates in android sqlite database 
I stored dates in the format

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

```
Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tableName+" WHERE SALESDATE BETWEEN '2020-1-01' AND '2020-2-01';",null);
```

It gives result with dates of month 10, 11 and 12 along with the dates between above specified dates.
I would like to know if it is a bug or is there any mistake in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your date literals are in a non standard (and likely incorrect) format.  Appreciate that the following inequality holds true:

```
'2020-10-01' > '2020-1-01' AND '2020-10-01' < '2020-2-01'
```

This is true because the text `10` is lexicographically larger than just `1`, but also less than `2`.  To avoid this problem, use proper date literals:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE SALESDATE BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-02-01';"
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Note that SQLite does not actually have a formal date type.  Thus, it is very important to *always* store your dates in SQLite using a proper ISO format.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your Date as long value in database. Simple new Date().getTime() gives you this value and new Date(long value) returns it back. So you can make such queries easy.

But what I can suggest is to:

- Export your table to CSV,
- Change the date values to a proper SQLite TimeString and
- Re-import the CSV after deleting the original table.

Then, you can run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE SALESDATE BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-01 23:59:59'
```